# Time Interval between two CORS requests using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, http

I am making CORS request to a web service using jQuery `$.ajax`. As per standard there is a pre-flight request and then the actual POST request.

What I have noticed is, there are two requests everytime I try to make a web service call (one pre-flight and one actual POST request) only If there is a time interval between the two requests.

If I keep making the web service call successively without any time gap (like less than 1 second between two requests) then the pre-flight is missing.

How can I avoid this pre-flight request every time?

What is this time interval?

Is this something specific to Chrome browser?

Answer (score 6):

There are differences between browsers in how they implement pre-flight caching. Unfortunately the W3C spec alone does not explain the nuances you've observed in pre-flight caching.

For others reading this question, I'd like to explain when the OP says *pre-flight request* he is referring to the `OPTIONS` request that precedes a cross-origin `POST` request. The `OPTIONS` request is used to query an API and determine which HTTP methods are permissible for cross-origin requests. Typically, you'd expect to see this type of response to an `OPTIONS` request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
```

Since you are working with **Google Chrome**, I will refer you to the applicable section of the **Webkit** source code:

https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/loader/CrossOriginPreflightResultCache.cpp

**The default pre-flight cache timeout is 5 seconds:**

```
static const auto defaultPreflightCacheTimeout = std::chrono::seconds(5);
```

**The maximum value is 5 minutes:**

```
static const auto maxPreflightCacheTimeout = std::chrono::seconds(600);
```

The server can specify a timeout value for pre-flight requests using the **`Access-Control-Max-Age`** field in the response header, however the **Webkit browser enforces a maximum timeout** of 5 minutes.

To answer your questions:

> How can I avoid this pre flight request every time?

You need to **set `Access-Control-Max-Age` to 600** in the header of your API response to the `OPTIONS` request.

> What is this time interval?

For Webkit browsers (i.e., Google Chrome) the default timeout value is **5 seconds**. That is why you are seeing the pre-flight request before each POST request, but if you rapidly submit POST requests, then you do not see additional pre-flight requests.

> Is this something specific to Chrome browser?

**Yes**, there are differences between browsers in how pre-flight caching is implemented. The W3C spec does not specify everything needed to build out pre-flight caching functionality in a web browser.

Comment: Solid and concrete answer

Answer (score 2):

The browser will not make a preflight request if the following two situations are true:

- For request method there either is a method cache match or it is a simple method and the force preflight flag is unset.
- For every header of author request headers there either is a header cache match for the field name or it is a simple header.

This reference shows the user agent (browser) responsibilities with CORS: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

Otherwise, you should not worry over it.  The browser implementation will do the right thing.